# GStreamer sequence number debug while streaming in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtp, gstreamer

I trying to stream RTP packets over UDP from camera source and displaying my stream in Android mobile and the application was working fine.

For sequence number and time stamping details,i have used   **gst_debug_set_threshold_from_string("rtph264depay:5",TRUE)** debug API before calling Gstreamer.init().But the debug information was not giving any details about Seq number or time-stamp.

I have attached my debug logcat details in the link [pastebin.com/QwmBTTiz](http://pastebin.com/QwmBTTiz)
I don't know how to proceed after this.Any idea

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it's at the TRACE level?  I think that's 7 instead of 5?

Comment: Thanks mpr for your reply.Even i tried with 7,but no gain in the output.I have added my pipeline details also.You can take a look at it.

Comment: data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch("udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false",&error);

Comment: What sequence number are you referring to?  Also what timestamp?  RTP packet timestamp?  H264 timing information?  The elements may just not output what you're looking for.  If by sequence number you mean frame number, I'm not sure you'll find that at the RTP level of things.

Comment: Here i'm referring everything with respect to rtp Packet level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see it in the rtpjitterbuffer element.  Set your logging:

> > > export GST_DEBUG=2,rtpjitterbuffer:7

Run your command (just pasting a random sample, note that rtpbin contains a rtpjitterbuffer):

> > > gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=6200 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=H264,media=video,clock-rate=90000 !  rtpbin  ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! deinterlace ! videoconvert ! queue ! ximagesink sync=false

Parse this output:

> > > 0:00:01.459130217  8308      0x244f280 DEBUG        rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:2540:pop_and_push_next: Pushing buffer 12446, dts 0:00:01.426670375, pts 0:00:01.422592897

You can browse the code directly for more details.  This may not be the exact file your version of GStreamer was compiled with though).

https://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/source/browse/trunk/Main/GStreamer/Source/gst-plugins-good/gst/rtpmanager/gstrtpjitterbuffer.c?r=440

Comment: Thanks mpr,that is what the thing which i'm looking for.Thanks a lot.